# could not find function "pdsi_get"

Tags: r, function

I'd like to download PDSI data from NOAA webstire using the following code:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("adamdsmith/pdsi")

pdsi_get(url = "climdiv-pdsist-v1.0.0-20190408", update = FALSE)
```

But I am getting this error:

> "could not find function "pdsi_get"".

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the package attached to your current session? ie have you typed `library(pdsi)` into your console?

Comment: Dear J. Moon. Thank you for your reply. No, it wasn't. Now it works.